# How can I redirect a request to a subdomain to another subdomain on Route 53?

Tags: redirect, jekyll, github-pages, amazon-route53

I have a GitHub Pages Jekyll blog at blog.Antrikshy.com. I have been meaning to move it to code.Antrikshy.com for a while now. I made the new address a CNAME for antrikshy.github.io on Amazon and wired everything correctly to make it work. Now my blog.Antrikshy.com URL is broken. How can I set it to redirect it to the new subdomain?

I'm new to this. Comment if you want any more information.

Preferably I'd like to do a 301 redirect and also retain the entire path, but that's not very important. I just want it to work, even if it means that users are redirected to the new home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could accomplish this with s3 website redirect[1].

- create a new s3 bucket with the name blog.antrikshy.com
- enable s3 website
- create an alias to blog.antrikshy.com bucket
- enable redirects on your website
- you can create redirects per page as well by creating a key for each page or redirect everything to your homepage

http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/10/04/web-page-redirects-on-amazon-s3-hosted-websites/

Comment: I found a blog that explained this and it worked! Can confirm, does 301 redirect, entire URL path remains unchanged.

Comment: it will not work for https. You need to use cloudfront to support both http & https