# Redirect https naked-domain to www in meteor

Tags: meteor, amazon-route53, flow-router

Can anyone help me? I already spent 3 days on it.

how can I redirect client https://example.com to https://www.example.com (also ROOT_URL) in meteor?

I tried with Route 53 & S3 for redirecting but these worked when https is not enabled.

Comment: AFAIK You'll need to redirect it yourself using your web server. How are you serving your meteor application?

Comment: I used mupx to deploy and I guess it uses nginx.

Comment: This is a common question in nginx - just do it there. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7958540/2805154

Comment: You can accomplish this using Route 53 + S3 + CloudFront.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388335/how-can-i-redirect-a-request-to-a-subdomain-to-another-subdomain-on-route-53/28400448#28400448

Comment: I tried but it broke when I have HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) enabled site.